# Direction of magnetic field, current carrying conductor and its motion

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics

In Fleming's left hand rule, we can see that if current is in direction of middle finger and magnetic field in the direction of fore finger, the thrust must act on the direction of the thumb. These three are mutually perpendicular. But isnt the opposite direction of the thumb is also perpendicular to remaining both of them? Then who fixed or selected one direction(the direction of thumb or can be taken as y-axis) from 2 possible directions which are opposite to each other( +ve and -ve y axis)? How can nature select an option from two options? Isnt that a logical selection? So my main question is why is thrust acts in +ve y-axis instead of -ve y axis?

Comment: The usage of the Fleming's left hand rule presupposes that the thumb is pointing in the correct direction. The opposite direction, that you are talking about, would be gotten with the Fleming's right hand rule, if that is what is wanted. Nature does not care about human conventions; even in mathematics, we just care about internal consistency, and both Fleming's left and right hand rules can be derived from the cross product, which incorporates the general (as in not-Fleming) right hand rule via definitions.